# Can I get the result of swap by logs?

Tags: uniswap

In transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x500f3250bf814df9f34b29c0c3029bdb1543c2e067f231781f27d28824dbebf0,
actually trader get 1,044,000,000.000000002 SAITOKI.

Can I calculate the result (1,044,000,000.000000002) by amount0In, amount1In, amount0Out or amount1Out.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several transfers happening here, so simply looking at swap event log will not be sufficient.

What you should do is find a transfer event, where sender is the pair contract and the receiver is the caller. In your case that is **event log number 4**.